# Event tracking code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-tracking

I am adding GA Event tracking code and listening for clicks.

In the below code I am creating the links dynamically using Javascript:

```
<c:forEach items="${higherStudiesSubCategory}" var="sub">
                           databb1=databb1 + '<a class="col-xs-4 Cfilter" id="higherstudies,${sub}" onclick="GetResultAccordingToSubCategory(this)">${sub}</a>';
                           option1=option1 + '<option value="${sub}">${sub}</option>';
                           $('#subcategory-menu').html(option1);
                           $('.category-all-filters').html(databb1);
                        </c:forEach>
```

After adding Event tracking code :

```
<c:forEach items="${higherStudiesSubCategory}" var="sub">
                           databb1=databb1 + '<a class="col-xs-4 Cfilter" id="higherstudies,${sub}" onclick="ga(send,event,SubCategory,click,'+location+':${sub});GetResultAccordingToSubCategory(this)">${sub}</a>';
                           option1=option1 + '<option value="${sub}">${sub}</option>';
                           $('#subcategory-menu').html(option1);
                           $('.category-all-filters').html(databb1);
                        </c:forEach>
```

The difference in the above code is the onclick function :

```
onclick="ga(send,event,SubCategory,click,'+location+':${sub});GetResultAccordingToSubCategory(this)"
```

But the above code does not fire the event (tracked through omnibug) as single quotes is missing in the above code. It should be:

```
onclick="ga('send','event','SubCategory','click','+location+':${sub});GetResultAccordingToSubCategory(this)"
```

But using the single quotes in the code gives javascript error. Please help me how can i add single quotes in my javascript onclick function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
'<a class="col-xs-4 Cfilter" id="higherstudies,${sub}" onclick="ga('+"'send'"+','+"'event'"+','+"'SubCategory'"+','+"'click'"+',\''+location+':${sub}\');GetResultAccordingToSubCategory(this)">${sub}</a>';
```

Comment: Thankyou vikas , the above code worked . Just a better solution is :                               `onclick="ga(\'send\',\'event\',\'SubCategory\',\'click\',\''+location+':${sub}\');GetResultAccordingToSubCategory(this)">${sub}</a>';`